# Function Undefined with Firebase SimpleLogin

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm struggling with implementing the FirebaseSimpleLogin functionality in my website. I've read all of their documentation and I'm really not making any progress. I think as well, they seem to have updated their documentation this week so lots of old guides and SO answers are out of date. I would really appreciate any help.

The main issue at the moment is that I keep seeing in my console that FirebaseSimpleLogin is not defined.

For the purposes of testing, I've got my page set up like this:

```
<body>
   <form id="login">
   <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="loginEmail" id="loginEmail" placeholder="email address" required><br>
   <input type="password" value="" name="EMAIL" class="password" id="password" placeholder="password" required><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    </form>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.15/firebase.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.4/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/signup.js"></script>
</body>
```

and I've got my js file (the signup.js one referenced in the html) like this:

```
var rootRef = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com");
var authClient = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(rootRef, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase
        console.log("User ID: " + user.uid + ", Provider: " + user.provider);
    } else {
        // user is logged out
    }
});
var loginEmail = $("#loginEmail").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
authClient.login('password', {
    email: loginEmail,
    password: password,
    rememberMe: true
});
```

Any pointers on how to get this working?

**UPDATE:**
I made sure I was loading the .js file for SimpleLogin after the script for the login page, but I'm still getting a "ReferenceError: $createUser is not defined". :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loading your javascript file before you loaded firebase-simple-login. Simply just move your script tag for loading signup.js to after firebase-simple-login:

```
<body>
   <form id="login">
   <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="loginEmail" id="loginEmail" placeholder="email address" required><br>
   <input type="password" value="" name="EMAIL" class="password" id="password" placeholder="password" required><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    </form>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.15/firebase.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.4/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/signup.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Ugh, feel like a total doofus. This is what I get for trying to do this so late. Thank you!

Comment: Authentication is now part of the core Firebase API, so you don't need to include Simple Login. You can call createUser() directly on your rootRef. Details are in the user auth guide here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html

Comment: Hey, thanks @Sara - really feeling a bit dumb with this, but I'm still getting createUser() is undefined, even with the Firebase (and Simple Login which should now be irrelevant) js called. Any tips?

Comment: @MeaghanFitzgerald looks like you need to include the latest version of the Firebase client: https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.0/firebase.js Let me know if that fixes it